# How to attach to linux container started with systemd?

Tags: debian, systemd, lxc

Long story short, I have a few unprivileged containers that run on boot that I used to be able to start from `rc.local`.  That no longer works, and currently start them with a systemd unit.  They start, but I cannot `lxc-attach -n <container>` to them.

Long story long, I run a base rolling Debian install (tracks stable, but can also pull from experimental, testing and unstable through preference files), with lxc 1:4.0.5-2 and systemd 247.2-5.  That was after an `apt-get -y dist-upgrade`.  The containers were created previous to the upgrade (before 24 Jan, 2021) and were started from rc.local with one line:

```
su -c "lxc-autostart -a" container-user
```

After some searching, I found I could start the containers through systemd after creating the following unit files:

```
#
# ~/.config/systemd/user/container.service
#
[Unit]
Description=lxc-autostart containers
DefaultDependencies=no
Wants=network.target lxc.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
Delegate=yes
ExecStart=lxc-autostart -a

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

```
#
# ~/.config/systemd/user/container.timer
#
[Unit]
Description=Timer to run container

[Timer]
OnBootSec=30

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

After a simple `systemctl --user enable container.timer`, the container starts 30 seconds after boot.  Without the timer, I see the service fail during boot.

Everything is great at that point, *as long as I don't have to attach to the container*.  Logging in as the user, and running `lxc-attach -n container` results in the following error:

```
lxc-attach: container: conf.c: userns_exec_minimal: 4236 Permission denied - Running parent function failed
```

After it fails like this, I usually have to `reset` the terminal so that I can see what I'm typing again.
Another thing I tried was to run `lxc-attach` with `systemd-run` (which is how I initially debugged starting the container) like so:

```
systemd-run --user -r -p "Delegate=yes" lxc-attach -n container
```

That prints out a message saying `Running as unit: run-<rando chars>.service` but no terminal.

I feel like I'm dancing around a solution, but I'm missing something crucial (or two, or three).  What's really annoying is that I can't freely add or remove packages from the containers anymore without stopping them, `su -` to `chroot` the rootfs of the container in question and then `apt-get install <package>`.  And even then, that seems wrong to do since the uid and gid are wrong for every single file that gets pulled in and installed that way, reflecting the **real** root uid and gid of the host system.  Oh, and also, I can `lxc-stop -n <container>` without `systemd-run`.  Getting the status of the `container.service` will show it as `active(exited)` after stopping it.

A few of the previously existing containers have `openssh-server` installed (when I was able to use `lxc-attach` freely), which is acceptable to me to administrate those containers, but, the templated containers I have been using (`lxc-create -n <new container> -t download -- -d debian -r buster -a amd64` for example) do not have an ssh server installed by default.

So after all that, what can I do to attach to these containers after they are started?  Am I really stuck stopping the containers, chroot'ing in to them to install packages and then finding all the new files installed to chown them to the correct container uids and gids?

Answer (score 0):

First off, I erroneously stated I was tracking the stable branch of Debian, but it turns out I am actually tracking testing.  I found this out after popping in to #debian-lxc on irc looking for answers.  A user there (Zhenech) mentioned their unprivileged containers run on stable, just like me?!?  `apt-cache madison lxc lxc-templates systemd` confirmed my mistake.  Tracked that down to my preferences files in `/etc/apt/preferences.d/`.

I'm hoping this weird problem will be solved in later versions of systemd and/or lxc, but my interim solution until then is to downgrade `lxc`, `lxc-templates` and `systemd` to their stable Debian packages, `1:3.1.0+really3.0.3-8`, `3.0.4-0+deb10u1` and `241-7~deb10u5` respectively.

I also tweaked the systemd unit `.service` file so I could properly stop the containers:

```
#
# ~/.config/systemd/user/container.service
#
[Unit]
Description=lxc-autostart containers
DefaultDependencies=no
Wants=network.target lxc.service

[Service]
Type=simple
RemainAfterExit=yes
Delegate=yes
ExecStart=lxc-start -n <container name>
ExecStop=lxc-stop -n <container name>

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Reminders for later:

- systemd 247.2-5 default-hierarchy=unified
- systemd 241 default-hierarchy=hybrid
- lxc 3.0.3 needs +2 number per interface /etc/lxc/lxc-usernet
- downgrading packages sucks